# I receive an empty list of notifications using the Connect REST API endpoint: /connect/notifications

Tags: rest-api, callout, notification, connect-api, empty

I want to get all the current user's notifications to display them in a LWC component. For this, I tried to make a REST API callout from Salesforce to the same Salesforce org using Connect REST API Resources (/connect/notifications — documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_notifications_resources.htm)

I tried to make the callout using first Workbench, then an apex class, but I always get the same result, **an empty list of notifications**. The current user has both custom and standard notifications, so I don't understand why I always get an empty list.

Does anyone have any idea why I receive an empty list of notifications?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be helpful for you today since the question was posted long back, although adding for reference of others visiting the questions.
The documentation for salesforce mentions that

> The API uses the context of the requesting connected app and returns notifications for the appropriate types.

Since you seem to accessing the API using rest explorer which uses the '**Workbench**' connected app  in SF to access Salesforce as per predefined policies. Since this app does not have the correct context of fetching the notifications data, hence you did not receive the necessary data. In order to verify your callout response you can trigger the callout from execute anonymous window using APEX HTTP request and response classes.

Please mark the response as answer, if you think it was helpful, or can be helpful for other searching for the same.